# d3v4 why are my line elements not appearing?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, data-visualization

I am in the process of making a simple set of boxplots on a graph, but for some reason the line elements are not showing up
Code is:

```
    var margin = {
        top: 10,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
    },
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var svgBox = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);


var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.05)
    .align(0.1);


var center = 200
var width = 100


d3.csv("boxPlotData.csv", function(dataset) {
    var max = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return +d.max;
    });
    yScale.domain([0, max])
    xScale.domain(dataset.map(function(d) {
        return d.borough;
    }));
    svgBox.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
    svgBox.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

    svgBox.selectAll("line").data(dataset).enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", d => xScale(d.borough) + width / 3.5)
        .attr("x2", d => xScale(d.borough) + width / 3.5)
        .attr("y1", d => yScale(+d.min))
        .attr("y2", d => yScale(+d.max))
        .attr("stroke", "black");


    svgBox.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", d => xScale(d.borough) + width / 3.5)
        .attr("y", d => yScale(+d.q3))
        .attr("height", d => (yScale(+d.q1) - yScale(+d.q3)))
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", "#69b3a2");
});
```

And my data is of the form

[Data CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGHRE.png)

The code is entering the "rect" elements as expected, but the line components aren't showing up anywhere in the html?

Comment: I did have selectAll, forgot to put it back into the code when asking the question (was erasing and modifying it to try and get it working). Same result with selectAll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you cannot just use `svgBox.selectAll("line")` because it will select the axis tick marks as well as the axis lines. Instead, I suggest add a class to your line with `attr("class", "line")` and use `svgBox.selectAll(".line")` to specifically select lines to append.

So the line append snippet should be:

```
  svgBox.selectAll(".line")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("x1", d => xScale(d.borough) + width / 3.5)
    .attr("x2", d => xScale(d.borough) + width / 3.5)
    .attr("y1", d => yScale(+d.min))
    .attr("y2", d => yScale(+d.max))
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

Here is the working snippet Block: https://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/4b29fb357ea7f02a1b47b611e03a5468/